# How can I detect/use low DTU time in Azure SQL Elastic Pool in near-real time?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have lower priority, asynchronous, but high DTU processes which I want to run in my Azure SQL Elastic Pool, but ONLY when it's not busy on standard workloads. Is there a way, in **near-real-time**, to detect those lulls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an alert rule for DTU percentage to detect when it drops below a certain threshold:

[image: DTU % < 10%, evaluated every minute]

Answer (score 0):

DTU usage is measured as a combination of CPU, IO, and Memory usage in your database. I think we can use the following sql query to detect in near-real-time.

```sql
 SELECT * FROM sys.dm_db_resource_stats ORDER BY end_time DESC
```